# Best way to read one line of command output to several variables

Tags: bash

I have a command that outputs a single line and I want to parse that output into several variables. I know of at least two ways with `read`:

```
read size dir <<< $(du -ks .)
read size dir < <(du -ks .)
```

Are there better alternatives (performance, conciseness, and readability)?

Comment: I usually use the 2nd one (w/ additional `-r`)

Comment: Another alternative will be `shopt -s lastpipe; du -ks . | read size dir` which may be readable if the preceding command is long and/or contains multiple pipelines but the preference may be opinion-based.

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with those variables.

Comment: If you use the first make sure to quote `"$(du -ks .)"`.

Comment: @tshiono Nice one, you could post it as an answer, but make it clear it only works in a script, you can't test it interactively.

Answer (score 2):

Using array

```
arr=($(du -ks .)) # create an array with values from command
size=${arr[0]}    # assign first value from array to var size
dir=${arr[1]}     # assign second value from array to var dir
```

check array values

```
echo ${arr[@]}    # print all items from array
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I don't see this as more concise, readable, or executing faster